# Bin folder not present in Java EE SDK

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, sdk

I want to install Eclipse + Java EE and achieve a "Hello World" example.
I have installed Eclipse which is OK.
However, I have downloaded Java EE SDK 8 from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-downloads-3908423.html) and unzipped the archive. I expected to get a folder named bin inside which I should find all the java commands, such as java, javac, etc.. so that I can declare this folder in the PATH environment.
But this folder is not there.

Why? What do I need to do?
Because of that, I cannot launch Eclipse because I get a message that I need a JRE installed.

Thanks a lot

Comment: This comment is opinion based only but in my experience netbeans is just so much easier to use.  As has been said by a famous javaEE developer, "sure you can install eclipse,  but you'll need 2 days to configure/download/update before you have what netbeans offers you out of the box".  Paraphrased, of course.

Comment: Java EE is essentally a big set of API's (i.e. interfaces).  You need a suitable server.  Netbeans come with Glassfish where things work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You´ve downloaded the reference implementation of Java 8 EE. So this is a Apllication Server u can use for your Java EE Application and Beanmanagement.
But it´s not equals to a normal JDK.

Download a JDK (Java SE) from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).